# What is the proper way to show a UIViewController/UIView over a UIView?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uistoryboard

I have a UIViewController with a UITableView and some buttons in each cell, one button is for show comments and make comments. What i need to do is show a "bubble view" like facebook comments over the current view, so if the user taps in other side i need to hide the bubble (just like facebook comments in photos).

I already have the bubble view, no problem with that, but my question is what is the proper way to show it, and create it in storyboard, because it have a tableview with the comments and a few buttons to make new comments.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to display another viewController you will have to look into creating a custom [container view controller](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers.html). The tableView will be the rootViewController and make the child's viewController ("bubble view") frame smaller. This is also necessary to properly forward events to the "bubble view".

Additional Readings/Tutorials

http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/implementing-container-containment-sliding-menu-controller/

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIViewController/childViewControllers

Comment: Thanks ! it's a "old" question so i find another way to do this, not like the "bubble view" but another way...but thanks a lot! it will help me in another time !